# Samsung CameraCaptureSession in WAITING_LOCK - Need a workaround

Tags: android, android-camera2, samsung-galaxy

UPDATED: Please mark this as duplicated of [Front Camera in Camera2 not capturing image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33127258/front-camera-in-camera2-not-capturing-image) Samsung S7 front camera does not support autofocus and lockfocus() will not return anything back.

It works on other devices with API24 , not in GalaxyS7.

```
private CaptureRequest.Builder mPreviewRequestBuilder;
/**
 * Initiate a still image capture.
 */
private void takePicture() {
    Log.e("timer", "entered takepicture()");
    lockFocus();
    Log.e("timer", "exited lockfocus()");
}

/**
 * Lock the focus as the first step for a still image capture.
 */
private void lockFocus() {
    try {
        // This is how to tell the camera to lock focus.
        Log.e("timer", "entered lockfocus()");
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER,
                CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_START);
        // Tell #mCaptureCallback to wait for the lock.
        mState = STATE_WAITING_LOCK;
        mCaptureSession.capture(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build(), mCaptureCallback,
                mBackgroundHandler);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

No errors/warnings in logcat.

```
02-10 17:52:26.626 11402-11402/xxx E/timer: entered takepicture()
02-10 17:52:26.626 11402-11402/xxx E/timer: entered lockfocus()
02-10 17:52:26.634 11402-11402/xxx E/timer: exited lockfocus()
02-10 17:52:28.652 11402-11529/xxx V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

If you need other pieces of the code please do let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Please mark this as duplicated of Front Camera in Camera2 not capturing image Samsung S7 front camera does not support autofocus and lockfocus() will not return anything back.